# How to list out the key for certain elements of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, mapping

I have a dictionary mapping:

```
k=[1,3,5,7,9]
matrix = { 1:[0,0], 2:[0,1], 3:[0,2], 4: [1,0], 5:[1,1], 6:[1,2], 7:[2,0], 8:[2,1], 9:[2,2]};
j=[matrix[i] for i in k]
print ("output=",j)
```

and the output is

```
output =[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2]]
```

My question is how to print back the keys for the certain elements in the dictionary matrix orderly as below:

```
key=[1,3,5,7,9]
```

I hope that somebody may help me in this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean like this:

`{k: matrix[k] for k in k}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
k=[1,3,5,7,9]
matrix = { 1:[0,0], 2:[0,1], 3:[0,2], 4: [1,0], 5:[1,1], 6:[1,2], 7:[2,0], 8:[2,1], 9:[2,2]};
print({i: v for i, v in matrix.items() if i in k})
```

This outputs:

```
{1: [0, 0], 3: [0, 2], 5: [1, 1], 7: [2, 0], 9: [2, 2]}
```

Or, if you would like to preserve the order prior to Python 3.6, you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print(OrderedDict(filter(lambda i: i[0] in k, matrix.items())))
```

This outputs:

```
OrderedDict([(1, [0, 0]), (3, [0, 2]), (5, [1, 1]), (7, [2, 0]), (9, [2, 2])])
```

Comment: I got this output. The arrangement of index is not in order:
   

`{1: [0, 0], 3: [0, 2], 9: [2, 2], 5: [1, 1], 7: [2, 0]}`

Comment: The order of dict is not preserved until python 3.6. I just updated my answer with a different solution. Use it if you're using an earlier version of python.

Comment: I will use the sorted() to print the key orderly. Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.